# parse sas .out into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

I receive a lot of data that look like this:

```
                                Even_
                  Long_var_     longer_var
  Obs Var1        name          name            ...
  =================================================
    1 xxx         23            lolz            ...
    2 yyy         34            foo             ...
    3 zzz         96            bar             ...
```

in the form of .out files from SAS.

If these were simple tab-delimited files, there'd be no problem, but SAS does some sort of magical pretty-printing where it linebreaks variable names to keep the columns lined up and repeats the headers every 60 or 70 lines or so. Because variables have different lengths (as in the example), sometimes this results in two lines of variable names, sometimes in three, and I can imagine breaking to four.

Let's say for a moment that I can't convince the programmers who deliver data this way to dump a nice clean csv or something.

The challenges are 3:

1. split variable names
2. line breaking
3. removal of repeated headers

I think I can handle three with a big stupid multi-line regex, but I don't have a clue how I'd handle 1 and 2 (not `pandas.read_fwf`, at least not without enough pre-processing that I'd have solved 1 and 2 by that point anyway).

Is there already a library somewhere in the pydata universe that does this? If not, any suggestions?

Comment: It's not all that hard but can be tedious and time-consuming.  Your best time investment is likely to be spent convincing (begging?) the programmers to output something more convenient.  It's ultimately much more accurate also.  I doubt there is a library (though maybe there is) b/c this is the whole point for CSVs, sas datasets, hd5, etc.

Comment: Thanks @JohnE, I agree. I think I'm going to work on an approach that solves the simplest case (no wrapping) and throw it into a gist as a starting point for others, but some work on it yesterday confirm the tedium. Definitely "begging" rather than convincing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

[TXR:](http://www.nongnu.org/txr)

Approach: use fixed-width variables to extract the nasty variable name columns. Some Lisp code to reconstitute them. When marching over the data, recognize repetitions of the header by the optional presence of a blank line using `@(maybe)`. If present, `@(skip)` that blank line and stuff that follows right up to the next `=====....`.

```
@(collect)
@{col1-hdr 3}@{col2-var 12}@{col3-var 14}@{col4-var}
@(last)
@/=====.*/
@(end)
@(set (col1-hdr col2-var col3-var col4-var)
      @[mapcar (opip (mapcar trim-str) cat-str)
               (list col1-hdr col2-var col3-var col4-var)])
@(collect)
 @col1 @col2 @col3 @col4
@  (maybe)

@  (skip)
@/=====.*/
@  (end)
@(end)
@(output)
@{col1-hdr 20} @{col2-var 20} @{col3-var 20} @{col4-var}
@  (repeat)
@{col1     20} @{col2     20} @{col3     20} @col4
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ cat data
                              Even_
                Long_var_     longer_var
Obs Var1        name          name
========================================
  1 xxx         23            lolz
  2 yyy         34            foo
  3 zzz         96            bar

                              Even_
                Long_var_     longer_var
Obs Var1        name          name
========================================
  4 aaa         12            quux
  5 bbb         45            xyzzy
  6 ccc         78            bork

$ txr data.txr data
Obs                  Var1                 Long_var_name        Even_longer_varname
1                    xxx                  23                   lolz
2                    yyy                  34                   foo
3                    zzz                  96                   bar
4                    aaa                  12                   quux
5                    bbb                  45                   xyzzy
6                    ccc                  78                   bork
```

This program cheats! It depends on the "longest varname" being the rightmost. What if the data contains shorter lines, like this, where `$` indicates end of line?

```
longest     $
var         shorter$
name        name        shortest$
```

One thing we can do is pad the input stream itself with spaces up to a given column: say ensure that all lines are padded up to 256 characters. The TXR pattern language actually processes a lazy list of strings implicitly produced from a data source. We can redirect it to instead march over an explicitly created lazy list which we massage. This can be done, for instance, by adding this line to the top:

```
@(next :list @(mapcar* (op format nil "~<256a") (get-lines)))
```

We also modify the column collecting match to not include the trailing spaces in the `col4` variable.

```
 @col1 @col2 @col3 @col4@/ +/
```

Lastly, since we used `(get-lines)` which reads from standard input (when not given an argument), we use:

```
$ txr data.txr < data
```